# Unable to launch the Jenkins console which is running on Linux box

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I just pulled the Jenkins image from docker hub by using below command.

```
sudo docker pull jenkins
```

`sudo docker run -p 7071:7071 -p 50000:50000 jenkins` this command help me to run the jenkins image inside the docker container
[image]

Now the problem is that I just want to run the Jenkins console to create a some sample test jobs. When I tried to access this from some windows machine I'm not able to connect and It returned 404 error code.

Tried to connect the Jenkins from Windows machine.

```
http://<ip address>:7071  -> this is failing to connect.
http://<ip address>:50000  -> This returning the Jenkins Agent Protocol details
```

Output:

> Jenkins-Agent-Protocols: JNLP-connect, JNLP2-connect, JNLP4-connect,
> Ping Jenkins-Version: 2.60.3 Jenkins-Session: cba34bd8 Client:
> XXXXXXXX Server: YYYYYYYY

Can someone help me since I'm new to docker + jenkins world and want to know how to connect the dockerized jenkins that is hosted in the Linux box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it is a type but =p should be -p

Comment: sorry. it was typo.. I just updated

Comment: You will need to map 8080 also. This will be the main port to access the Jenkins web console.

Comment: Great...! I just publish the port 8080 and It worked now...! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main port used by Jenkins for access via the web console is 8080 and so add:

```
docker run ... -p 8080:8080
```